# How to bind two keyboards one to each of the two monitors?

Tags: keyboard, multiple-monitors

**My setup**: a monitor, keyboard, and mouse connected to a laptop.

On the dual screen setup I code on the external monitor, and use the laptop screen to follow along tutorials.

Is there a way to limit the external keyboard to apps on the external monitor only, and the laptop keyboard to apps on laptop screen? I want to use the external keyboard for my coding stuff and, at the same time being able to use the laptop keyboard's left and right arrows to rewind and fast-forward the tutorials on the laptop screen without the need to `alt+tab` into the video player screen first.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to limit the external keyboard to apps on the external
> monitor only, and the laptop keyboard to apps on laptop screen?

No.

The monitor(s) are bound to the video circuit and output inside the computer.

The keyboard and mouse are bound to the input side of the computer.

There is no control outside the computer to attach a specific keyboard to a specific monitor, or to a specific app when another app is active.

I am fairly sure (having looked inside and repaired computers) that there is no inside path from input to video.

So no. You are limited to Alt-Tab to look at the other app (the tutorial).

What I use is a second computer (say for Zoom) while my agenda and documents are on the first computer. That works well.